# Get number of tokens in a curve pool

Tags: solidity, curve

Is it possible to determine the number of tokens used in a Curve pool from a contract? Curve pools typically have a constant **N_COINS** in the contract, but since it's not public, it can't be read. Are there any other options available to obtain the token count?